# After change orientation searchview takes the entire screen

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I have this problem after change orientation:
[image]

I would have screen like this:

[image]

I saw That problem in a lot of app, only Note doesn't has it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Toolbar` menu to search then update this like below in your `Activity/Fragment`

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu) {
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setImeOptions(searchView.getImeOptions() | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);

    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line to the EditText or in SearchView

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"

 <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```